# Problems to find nearby Locations in android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) tutorial to get nearby location, I followed each and every step as per tutorial. But when I run my app, I'm getting following errors:

```
10-08 10:57:37.125: E/dalvikvm(758): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.<clinit>
10-08 10:57:37.475: E/dalvikvm(758): Could not find class 'com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces$1', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.createRequestFactory
10-08 10:57:37.515: E/dalvikvm(758): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.getPlaceDetails
10-08 10:57:37.566: E/dalvikvm(758): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.search
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:170)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  ... 4 more
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.<clinit>(GooglePlaces.java:23)
10-08 10:57:37.645: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  ... 8 more
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758): Activity com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40936600 that was originally added here
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40936600 that was originally added here
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:288)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:249)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:532)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:269)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:162)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:549)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:499)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-08 10:57:38.715: E/WindowManager(758):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 11:04:08.085: E/dalvikvm(794): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.<clinit>
10-08 11:04:08.435: E/dalvikvm(794): Could not find class 'com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces$1', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.createRequestFactory
10-08 11:04:08.485: E/dalvikvm(794): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.getPlaceDetails
10-08 11:04:08.655: E/dalvikvm(794): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.search
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:170)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  ... 4 more
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.<clinit>(GooglePlaces.java:23)
10-08 11:04:08.685: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  ... 8 more
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794): Activity com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@409365d0 that was originally added here
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@409365d0 that was originally added here
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:288)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:249)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:532)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:269)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:162)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:549)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:499)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-08 11:04:09.786: E/WindowManager(794):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 11:08:51.366: E/dalvikvm(826): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.<clinit>
10-08 11:08:51.806: E/dalvikvm(826): Could not find class 'com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces$1', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.createRequestFactory
10-08 11:08:51.885: E/dalvikvm(826): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.getPlaceDetails
10-08 11:08:51.935: E/dalvikvm(826): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl', referenced from method com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.search
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:170)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  ... 4 more
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.<clinit>(GooglePlaces.java:23)
10-08 11:08:52.035: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  ... 8 more
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826): Activity com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40936608 that was originally added here
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40936608 that was originally added here
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:288)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:249)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:532)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:269)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:162)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:549)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:499)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-08 11:08:53.145: E/WindowManager(826):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I searched to solve errors, but can't succeeded. How can I overcome those errors?
Or Can anyone provide me better solution to find nearby location?

Comment: From your error it shows that you are trying to open the popup or alert dialog in the doInBackground method. You can not open the dialog in doInBackground method. Try to open it in onPostExecute method. Do not try to update UI in thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jars are not being added properly. You must explicit add library reference of google-http-client-1.5.0-beta.jar(right click project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add External JARs), don't believe class path. If you do not do this, in the apk file does not contain the required data.
You can download Google plus library from  [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/1.5.0-beta)

Hmm... not working...??? Make sure one more thing as in pic that all options are checked e.g :
[image]