# Android location(latitude and longitude)

Tags: java, android, latitude-longitude

I am trying to find out the latitude and longitude of other/desired locations. Please keep in mind that i am not asking about to get the latitude and longitude of current location.

Also i need to find out nearby places of other/desired locations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you dig a google properly you could find the solution from google developers official site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems to find nearby Locations in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239940/problems-to-find-nearby-locations-in-android)

Comment: @Abhilash Karanth use google places api using this just enter the name of the place you will get its address longitude and latitude.

Comment: yeah ! Place Picker API is easy to implement and will help you surely.

Comment: @userI can you please provide the related links?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940721/google-places-api-autocomplete-get-cities-list-only/51942073#51942073

Comment: look the link above and remove .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES) and find every detail of place selected

Answer (score 0):

Just go to developers console and enable the places-api
refer [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup) link for enabling api or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302920/how-do-i-get-a-google-places-api-key-for-my-android-app) link
and do the following code

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
```

MainActivity.java

```
String location=null;
   PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);



        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i(TAG, "Place===: " + place.getName());
                location=place.getName().toString();
 if(location!=null || !location.equals("")) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());

                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);

                    String place_name = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    String latitude=address.getLatitude();
                    String longitude= address.getLongitude());


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred===: " + status);
            }
        });
```

In manifest.xml add the following lines

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and under application tag add

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

try this code.